# how to make a dynamic table cell a link

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm working on shopping site, i want when a user clicks on picture of a product, it takes them to a different page that displays the details of the product they clicked on, please i need help on how to achieve this. thanks.

```html
my code 

<tr>
<td id="menTd" width="40px" height="50px"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${proDetails.mode4}" height="200" width="182"/><br>
                            ${proDetails.brand}<br>
                            ${proDetails.name}<br>
                            ${proDetails.gender}<br>
                            ${proDetails.price}
                    </td> 
                    
</tr>
```

Comment: could u pls send me link to answer, thanks @BalusC

Comment: Check top of question.

Comment: ok seen it thanks @BalusC